# How do I run 2 discord bots at once

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, bots, discord

I'm using Ubuntu (Linux) VPS hosted by Time4VPS.eu. I'm currently hosting one of my Discord bots using Node.JS and discord.js. I want to run 2 bots at once, how do I do this?

I've tried using this command without luck.

```
cd bot; node bot.js; cd; cd bot2; node bot.js
```

Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), install it with: `npm install pm2 -g` and then you can just run:

```
cd bot
pm2 start bot.js
cd ../bot2
pm2 start bot.js
```

PM2 would run the bots on the background. Or you could use screens to keep the bots running.
If you just run node bot.js on a SSH connection, after you stop that connection the bot would stop.